# Issue with accessing a file after renaming it

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, oledb, ssis-2012

Step1: I have a script task at first to get excel file at a specific location and delete few lines of data and then rename the file to "Report.xlsx" the same location.

Step2: Now I have a Data Flow task, I have used an Excel Source to load rename excel file by specifying the "FilePath+Report.xlsx" in the Excel File Path of Excel Connection Manager and selected the Sheet1$ as Name of the Excel sheet.

**My Goal** is to get the file in that location => rename the file to "Report.xlsx" => then load the data from excel to table.

But when I run the report, I am getting the below error

> Error at Work_Data [Excel Source [2]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E37.
>
> Error at Work_Data [Excel Source [2]]: Opening a rowset for "Sheet1$" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.
>
> Error at Work_Data [SSIS.Pipeline]: "Excel Source" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
>
> Error at Work_Data [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation.
>
> Error at Work_Data: There were errors during task validation.

My guess is that, the Excel Connection Manager trying to access the Report.xlsx report which will not be there before renaming (I guess).

Is there a way to achieve my Goal ?

Comment: SSIS validates the *entire* package before it processes it. If a file that a task is going to use will *not* exist when the package starts (but would be created during it) you need to set that task's `DelayValidation` property to `True`; then it will validate the task at the point the task is run, not the package.

Comment: Side note, as well, it's not actually a problem of accessing it *after* the rename, it's a problem of SSIS trying to validate the file *before* it's been renamed. SSIS is validating the Data Flow task *before* you renamed it, and generates the error then (as the file does not exist). It's not failing the first task *after* you renamed it.

Comment: Great answers @Larnu, you should drop them into the box below and get some points :D Also, they might need to set DelayValidation to True on the Excel Connection Manager itself